# Keep printing a number until the number is equal to 1 in Java

Tags: java

I have a code which generates a random number and prints a sequence of numbers starting with this random number. I want the sequence to end when the number is equal to 1.

This is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
package Collatz;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Random;

class Collatz {

    PrintStream out;

    Collatz() { 
        out = new PrintStream(System.out); 
    }

    void start() {
        int number = 0; 
        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(100);
        number = rand;
        for(;;) {
            if(number % 2 == 0) {
                number = number / 2;
                out.printf("%d \n",number);
            }
            if(number % 2 != 0) {
                number = (3* number) + 1;
                out.printf("%d \n",number);
                if(number == 1){
                    out.printf("%d \n",number);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        new Collatz().start();
    }
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: It keeps printing numbers after it already has reached the number 1.

Comment: The logic is wrong, it enters on the first "if" but never on the second one when number is 0. because number should be 0 (zero) to number be 1....but 0 % 2 is 0

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```java
            if(number % 2 != 0) {
                number = (3* number) + 1;
                out.printf("%d \n",number);
                if(number == 1){
```

You turn the number from 1 into an even number (by multiplying by 3 and adding 1) before checking whether it's one. An even number won't be 1.

To fix it, check whether `number` is 1 *before* changing `number`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void start() {
    int number = 0; 
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(100);
    number = rand;
    while(number!=1) {
        if(number % 2 == 0) {
            number = number / 2;
            out.printf("%d \n",number);
        }
        if(number % 2 != 0) {
            number = (3* number) + 1;
            out.printf("%d \n",number);
        }
    }
    out.printf("%d \n",number);
}
```

You are updating the number before checking if the number is '1' or not which might be giving you that issue. Instead of breaking from the 'for' loop, just change the loop to a while which will check if the number is '1' or not. If it is, then the loop won't be executed. Finally print the number i.e., '1'. Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

```
package Collatz;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Random;

class Collatz {

    PrintStream out;

    Collatz() { 
    out = new PrintStream(System.out); 
    }

void start() {
    int number = 0; 
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(100);
    number = rand;
for(;;) {
if(number % 2 == 0) {
    number = number / 2;
        out.printf("%d \n",number);
        }
if(number == 1){
        out.printf("%d \n",number);
        break;
        }
if(number % 2 != 0) {
    number = (3* number) + 1;
    out.printf("%d \n",number);
    }

}
}
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    new Collatz().start();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you changed and why that helped.